# How to Calculate Hand Odds in Texas Hold'em

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds, poker-theory, resources

What resources are available for mastering how to calculate current-hand odds in Texas Hold'em? ...books, websites, computer or phone apps are all helpful.

Note: On the iPhone I have found the `OddsTeacher` and `PkrCruncher` apps, which are useful, but I am looking for more explanatory and professional resources.

Comment: Please check out [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff - I have read that blog post, and I'm still not entirely sure why you think this question "has no answer" or is not constructive. A list of tools others' experience in using them is a very good "how" question, and would be useful to many enthusiasts. What is bad about this question?

Comment: I also read the "Good subjective / Bad subjective" blog post and still do not see why this should be closed.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer I have to agree with Rebecca here. The two answers you see on the question so far are an example of why questions like this are discouraged across the Stack Exchange network - they are short, mostly just links, and voting on them is just a matter of personal preference. There is no objective way to evaluate the answers, and so the question isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange's Q&A model. I agree that the site needs questions, but more than that you need *good* questions. Perhaps this one could be rephrased to be about the math involved rather than a list of tools?

Comment: All the tools do is help you learn the math. I figured "calculating hand odds" was "math" and that i said books, websites, computer or phone apps left it open for resources... also, some stacks are more about theory like Programmers for instance when things do not always have a right answer. Poker for instance will be one of those stacks whether its creators want it to or not... because other than did i count 7/52 cards right, its all theory and play style.

Comment: for the record - http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-can-i-do-to-calculate-my-odds-in-a-hand - notice how the most votes when to a tooling answer not the simple math formula that someone "estimated" - the question is practically the same, might as well just delete this one then

Answer (score 1):

This tool may help: [Equilab](http://www.pokerstrategy.com/software/10/)
It covers the functionality of the popular Pokerstove and offers more analysis.

This video provides a walkthrough:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPyIC1nEaRk

Answer (score 1):

[Pokerstove](http://www.pokerstove.com/) is the de facto tool for Texas Hold'Em odds calculation on the PC.

Comment: +1 and... People have used "winbottler" to port/convert PokerStove to OS X ; )