# How to calculate win percentages during a showdown?

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds, showdown

I've been trying to figure out how to calculate win percentages during a 2-3 hand showdown.
Up until now i know how to get to the percentages on the right side of the image (was taken from an online odds calculator).
Can anyone please explain to me how do i get to the percentages on the left side?
(i must say i Googled it countless times and couldn't find a satisfying explanation)

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do  to calculate my odds in a hand?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-can-i-do-to-calculate-my-odds-in-a-hand)

Comment: Unfortuntely no. I know how to calculate the percentages on the right square and i do so by using the simpler formula that the guy mentioned (the first one). However i can't understand how to transform the data in the right square to the data in the left square to get a final result. The explanation about the second formula isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck thinking about the probability of winning directly from outs instead of using the table on the right. In particular, you win if any diamond except the 2 comes out. That means you have 8 cards in the deck that make you win the hand. There are 44 cards remaining in the deck, so your probability of winning is 8/44 = 18.18%.

Comment: Thanks nosyarg. But what if i have 2 other players and want to calculate the win percentages for the three of us? how complicated does it get? I'm looking for any formula that will allow me to do so after the flop and after the turn (in case of a showdown).

Comment: same method works, you can see which cards make each player win, then divide those cards by the number of unknown cards to get each player's equity in the hand. It gets a little more complicated when you have not seen the turn yet b/c you have to think about all the 2-card combinations that make you win (and there are usually a whole lot of them), so at that point I always just use a computer to calculate equity.